# Why can I run a simple counter application through an android simulator but not through an ios simulator?

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I am trying to run a sample application that creates a counter on both an android simulator and an ios simulator. The android simulator is created through android studio and the ios simulator is created through xcode. The application works well on the android simulator, but not on the ios simulator when following the same steps. Any ideas on how to fix this?

This is what the return is:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           10.8s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **
```

Xcode's output:

```
↳
    ld: framework not found Flutter
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
    warning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To resolve this, select a development team in the Runner editor. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11.
```

Comment: Did you *read* the output? "ld: framework not found Flutter" - pretty much tells you what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Type in your shell `open ios/Runner.xcodeproj` the on XCode go to Runner -> Targets Runner -> All
And check you have a Team selected and also if it's a physical device you granted the permission on the iPhone.

Steps: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qeh7p.png